# I want to alert the color name when each div reaches the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to alert the color name when each div reaches the top.

```js
$(function(){
 console.log($('#one').offset());
 console.log($('#two').offset());
 console.log($('#three').offset());
 console.log($('#four').offset());
 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.common').each(function(index, element) {
            var getId = $(this).attr('id');
   if($('#' + getId).offset().top === $(this).offset().top){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   }
        });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 
}
.common {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 700px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#one {
 background:red;
}
#two {
 background:blue;
}
#three {
 background:green;
}
#four {
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="common" id="one"></div>
<div class="common" id="two"></div>
<div class="common" id="three"></div>
<div class="common" id="four"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you observe happening? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @TarynEast if it works , i implement this code to my website with other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this version I've used `this.getBoundingClientRect().top` and checked if it's less than or equal to zero, i.e. at the top of the viewport or beyond. We're looping through the panels in reverse order so that we can stop as soon as one was at the top of the viewport. Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $($('.common').get().reverse()).each(function(index, element) {
   var getId = $(this).attr('id');

   if(this.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0){
    console.log(getId);
    return false; // This breaks the jQuery `each` loop.
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 
}
.common {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 700px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#one {
 background:red;
}
#two {
 background:blue;
}
#three {
 background:green;
}
#four {
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="common" id="one"></div>
<div class="common" id="two"></div>
<div class="common" id="three"></div>
<div class="common" id="four"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you mean you want to be alerted only once when the panel hits the top, and then not again, you could try setting the comparison to `===` rather than `<=`, but you may never see it fire, since the `scroll` event may not happen when the panel is exactly at the top of the viewport.

In that case, you could instead use the [`IntersectionObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: yes i am looking for this. thanks for the answer. but some issue on this code. when we scroll its repeating the id like ( one two , one tow , one tow three) ,

Comment: if red on the view port my console need to show only red div id , and when we get blue on the viewport console shows blue div id, which one is the viewport alert that id only. is it possible ?

Comment: You want that every time the user scrolls, or just when the visible colours change?

Comment: nop thats not what i wanted.. i have set an action when the particular div on the viewport

Comment: I have updated my snippet to only log the bottommost matching panel. Is that what you want? I don't understand your latest comment.

Comment: its almost done.. i have a dot navigation on the right side window.. i need to change the active class depend on this divs

Comment: I've answered your question; now you're asking a different one. You could for example have `data-for="one"` etc on each of the dots, and then loop through the dots, and test that data attribute against the ID of the current top panel, such as `$(this).toggleClass('active', getId === $(this).data('for'));`. You'd have to change the code a little for that (use a conditional and flag instead of breaking, perhaps). But you should really look at IntersectionObserver as I suggested for this.

Comment: brother thanks for your answer.. i will work on it. if i get any doubt i can contact you..